# how to create docker-build n Docker file after pushed from dockerhub(Error response from daemon: unexpected error reading Dockerfile)

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile, dockerhub, docker-build

am new to docker I am unable to run the docker code which is pulled from docker hub

1.Windows 10 pro, 64bit

2.able to run hello-world

3.C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Dockerfile>docker version
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           19.03.5
 API version:       1.40
 Go version:        go1.12.12
 Git commit:        633a0ea
 Built:             Wed Nov 13 07:22:37 2019
 OS/Arch:           windows/amd64
 Experimental:      false

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          19.03.5
  API version:      1.40 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.12.12
  Git commit:       633a0ea
  Built:            Wed Nov 13 07:29:19 2019
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          v1.2.10
  GitCommit:        b34a5c8af56e510852c35414db4c1f4fa6172339
 runc:
  Version:          1.0.0-rc8+dev
  GitCommit:        3e425f80a8c931f88e6d94a8c831b9d5aa481657
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.18.0
  GitCommit:        fec3683

4. C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Dockerfile>docker push mydockerhub/shoprite:latest
   pulled successfully

5.**PROBLEM**
C:\Program Files\Docker\newfile>docker build -t mydockerhub/shoprite:latest .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  4.096kB
**Error response from daemon: unexpected error reading Dockerfile: read /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder712136353/Dockerfile: is a directory**

6.Error:
I also want used commands: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1aRt71Vtx13IbGLlcMzH-CyESvudLrCAnHg6fG9Zx3eU/edit

Q1.how to create Dockerfile and docker build

Answer (score 1):

If you are using **docker-compose.yml**
Just specify Dockerfile name

**Wrong**
dockerfile: ./

**Correct**
dockerfile: ./Dockerfile

Answer (score 0):

You can already see the problem at step 3.  You created Dockerfile as a directory. It is a file. Delete the directory and make sure you have a file called Dockerfile in the directory where you run `docker build`. Make sure that Dockerfile is correctly edited.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a dockerfile located somewhere in a file, first go to that file through commands i.e. `cd ./onedrive/desktop/newfolder/docker/`.

Then run command `docker build . -t <your imagename : your image tag>`

Here `.` gives you a default path where all the files in the local directory get `tar`d and sent to the Docker daemon. `-t` gives you chance to give your image a name with a tag separated by `:`.

You then need to use the `docker run` command i.e. `docker run <option/command> imagename`.

It will give you a writeable **container layer** over the specified image, and then starts it using the specified command.

Use command `docker ps` to see if you have created a container with the image name you used. If not, there is probably a problem with how you are doing it or your pc environment.

**P.S.** You need to understand that `dockerfile` is a docker file, not a directory. So, if you see that your current directory is `something/something/docker/dockerfile`, you made a mistake. The **dockerfile** goes into **docker** folder by default.

**Good luck**